# What shapes can be made with 144 tetrahedron? Or multiples 288, 432?

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry, combinatorial-geometry, platonic-solids

I am wondering if there are any shapes that appear with this number of tetrahedron, similar to the 64 tetrahedron grid with 64.

I am looking at the number `144 (12^2)`, and/or the multiples, `288`, `432`

The reason for this is I am looking for a good way to visualize this amount of tetrahedrons.

Here is an image showing other shapes that can be made of the tetrahedron (lots of cubes)

[image: Image of]

Comment: The centres of the 8 tetrahedra in your second shape are on the vertices of a cube. This suggests that you can pick any subset of the cube lattice $\Bbb Z^3$ and center a tetrahedron on each picked point (with orientation depening on coordinate parity). Trivially, this allows us to use $12\cdot 144$ tertrahedra for a cube of side length $12$.